# When should one's field of study be capitalized?

Tags: grammar

I've seen people capitalize their field of study:

> > I'm studying ***Planetary Science***.
> >
> > She teaches ***Computational Physics*** at the university.

Other people leave it uncapitalized:

> > How long have you studied ***biology***?
> >
> > He earned her degree in ***applied mathematics***.

#### When should one's field of study be capitalized?

Are there rules that govern this?

Comment: Might this be more on-topic at [English Language](https://english.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange? This isn't specific to academia- it's just grammar.

Comment: I suspect that capitalization is generally used to refer to a formal degree program, course, or etc. while lowercase refers to the field itself, e.g. Computational Physics sounds like a course in which computational physics is taught.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with English usage, not academia.

Comment: @astronat Fair enough. Is anyone able to port it? If not, I'll remake it.